# condicionales con modulo y booleanos

Tags: javascript

una consulta, como puedo escribir una funcion de modulo,y los valores booleanos.

tengo que escribir una funcion que reciba un numero, y que cumpla con la siguientes condiciones 
- que sea positivo 
- multiplo de 2 o 3 
- y no puede ser el numero 15

pero con la condicion que no se use **If**, solo **Return**

```
function esNumeroDeLaSuerte (numero){
        return numero >= 0 && (numero %2 ) && (numero % 3  ) && ( numero>15< numero );
}
console.log(esNumeroDeLaSuerte(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
return ((numero > 1) && (((numero%2) == 0) || ((numero%3) == 0)) && (numero!=15))
```

(numero > 1) porque te piden que sea positivo y multiplo de 2 ó 3, si pones (numero >= 0) cuando evalúas el módulo de 2 ó 3 el resultado será igual que si el número es múltiplo de 2 o 3

Ejemplo: `((numero%2) == 0)`
Entonces
((0%2) == 0) --> TRUE
((4%2) == 0) --> TRUE

Tienes que evaluar si el módulo del número es 0 para 2 ó para 3, no && (AND) pero || (OR)

```
((numero%2) == 0) || ((numero%3) == 0)
```

(numero!=15) identifica si el número es diferente a 15

Por último, te recomiendo utilizar los paréntesis lo mejor posible para identificar cada condición por separado

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function esNumeroDeLaSuerte(numero)
{
    return ((numero>=0 && numero!=15) &&((numero%2==0) || (numero%3==0)));
} 
console.log(esNumeroDeLaSuerte(55));
</script>
```

Comment: Una buena practica es explicarle al OP lo que trataste de hacer con tu codigo, considera eso en tu respuesta